# How are these right cosets not identical? (Are they?)

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group $G$ which is a set of integers under addition. Then a subgroup of $G$ is $H_2=\{...,-4,-2,0,2,4,..\}$. Now consider, $H_4=\{...,-4,0,4,...\}$ which is also a subgroup of $G.$

Certainly these two subgroups of $G$ above have common elements but they are not identical since $2$ is not in $H_4$.

Also, trivially the two-subgroups $H_2$ and $H_4$ form two right cosets $H_2$ and $H_4$

I read in Herstein that either two right cosets have no element in common or they are identical.

In the above case this is not true.

So, is the claim in Herstein valid only for finite groups?

Edit: Herstein wrote the complete unambiguous statement. I misread it and misunderstood it.

Here's the quote from Herstein

> Thus any two right cosets of $H$ in $G$ either are identical or have no element in common.

He has defined $H$ above as being a subgroup of $G.$

Comment: Did you have a specific group in mind for $G$?  And when you speak of cosets, which subgroup are you referring to?

Comment: This is all very vague.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: You only have $H_4$ as a subgroup of $H_2$. Your $H_4$ is not a coset modulo $H_2$.

Comment: Please check if the edis help.

Comment: It's still too vague.  You can't just speak of "cosets".  You have to say what the group and the subgroup are.  And don't toss around words like "trivially", especially when you are just learning a subject.

Comment: Two cosets **of the same subgroup** are either identical or disjoint. Your two different subgroups are each cosets of themselves but not cosets of each other.

Comment: Was just typing that out. I meant subgroups themselves form cosets since $H_2e$ is a coset.

Comment: Yes. But you understand why Herstein's comment is not applicable to your example, right?

Comment: The claim you reference holds for a fixed group and a fixed subgroup.

Comment: There are only two cosets modulo $H_2$ and only four cosets modulo $H_4$.

Comment: @runway44. Oh my god. I will have to reread Herstein from the start again now. Such a silly misunderstanding!

Comment: @runway44 Should I delete the question since it will unnecessarily waste viewer's time or is that not allowed?

Comment: you don't need to do that

Comment: It would help if you quoted Herstein exactly, presumably with some context. It is possible that Herstein simply assumed you understood he meant “two cosets of the same subgroup,” or it is possible you missed text that implies this.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Done. I misunderstood the text.

Answer (score 0):

For your convenience:

With $H_2$ you have
$$H_2 +0=H_2,$$
and
$$H_2 +1=\{...,-3, -1,1,3,...\}.$$

And for $H_4$
$$H_4+0=H_4,$$
and
$$H_4+1=\{...,-3, 1, 5,9,...\},$$
$$H_4+2=\{...,-2, 2, 6,10,...\},$$
$$H_4+3=\{...,-1, 3, 7,11,...\}.$$

Comment: please, comment if you got the pattern

Comment: This doesn’t address the OP’s question, which has to do with a misreading of Herstein regarding disjoint cosets.